# Obiee measures show null values only

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, obiee

I have the following problem. In obiee when I create analysis from table A, its measure columns showing null, even though in database there are no null values in this table.

I used only this table and did not select any columns from other tables. Non-measure columns are fine though like client_id, client_name. However any calculated in rpd measure of that table shows null. 
What can be the reason?

**Edit.** Log has the following : 
The expression "measure_column" is converted to null because 
None of the fact tables are compatible with the query request

Comment: It looks like you have serious model issues in your RPD. Is your measure really a *measure* in a logical fact table? Are your attributes really attributes residing in logical dimension tables?

Comment: The table itself is a dimension table containing some measure columns. It is not a fact table

Comment: I agree that my model is not perfect, as you said I shouldn't have measures in dimension tables. I fixed it with creating these measures in fact table only, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have measure columns in your dimensions it's time to completely go over what was done in the RPD. it seems to have severe issues built in.